# In R, how can I keep the names of vector elements after applying str_replace_all?

Tags: r, vector, str-replace

I noticed that the function `str_replace_all()` removes the names of the elements in my character vector. Does anyone know how to work around this, so I get to keep the names of the elements after applying `str_replace_all()`?

Here is an example of the problem, where I create a vector with named elements and replace all occurances of the character "c" with an "x". You can see that I am able to access the first element of the vector with `testvec["first"]` before the call to `str_replce_all`, but not after.

```
> testvec <- c("first"="abc", "second"="bcd", "third"="cde")

> testvec["first"]
first 
"abc" 

> testrepl <- str_replace_all(testvec, "c", "x")
> testrepl["first"]
[1] NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that would work. Maybe I could have stated it clearer, but I need to be able to access the elements using names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a line where you assign `names` of `testvec` to the `names` of `testrepl`:

```r
testrepl <- str_replace_all(testvec, "c", "x")
names(testrepl) <- names(testvec)

testrepl["first"]
# first 
# "abx"
```